# how do I smooth an object together?

Tags: sculpting

Weird title, I'm sure, but I'm trying to sort of smooth some objects together... I started by making four pieces. Then I joined the four pieces into one, thinking I could use the smooth tool to make it look less...jointed. 
[image: Pic of what I'm working on]

As an example, I went and tried to smooth it, but instead of it making it look less segmented, this is what happened

[image]

please be gentle I don't use Blender a lot.

Comment: hello, if these are 4 distinct meshes, they will remain 4 meshes even if you try to smooth them, it will be hard to fake a welding. By the way you don't say what you tried. Anyway you have several solutions: you can use the boolean tool to make one object, then smooth with a brush, which must be the easiest solution, or you can join their vertices with some bridges and fill... Another trick is to use a welding node that will fake the welding, I don't know if it's already available...

Comment: It is one object, I think...I joined them all together and now I can pick it up and move it as I like. The other meshes are now gone, it is now just called 'sphere 7' instead of '3,4,5,6'.

I used the smoothing brush with sculpting and instead of smoothing those 4 objects together, it only made it thinner and wouldn't smooth them together.

Here's a pic showing it's only one object [link](https://i.gyazo.com/40ef8c7d919c4c90dde54dbd5bf38ad2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you've joined several objects to make one object but it is still made of several separate meshes. As long as they are separate you won't be able to create any welding, except a fake one with this welding node but I don't know if it's already available. So the simplest is to use the *Boolean* tool: Go in *Edit* mode, select all your meshes except one (use <kbd>L</kbd> to select a mesh), go in the horizontal header menu > *Face* > *Intersect (Boolean)*, and in the operator box (bottom left of the 3D View), choose *Boolean* > *Union*. Now your meshes are merged into one and you can create a welding effect, in sculpting mode if you want, or with bevels...

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to get to the selecting part. I'm pressing L but it is only bringing up the menu on what to make local? it isn't doing anything to select the parts

Comment: Go in Edit mode, put your cursor over a vertex and press L, it will select the mesh this vertex is part of

Comment: ok so i tried doing that. i did what you said. it selected everything. but it's still treating it as separate meshes, and for some reason there's like a sub mesh or something? it says sphere 4 but i ican expand it and it says sphere 6, but it won't let me sculpt on that.

Comment: as I said select all your meshes except one, then boolean them. What do you mean by sub mesh? Maybe share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i'm sorry i'm an idiot, i clicked all of them instead of just one.
but i'm stil haivng some issue smoothing out the creases in the one mesh. it seems to sort of be working but the mesh looks kinda broken and lumpy when i do that. and it still is making it smaller on the head but I guess I can't fix that until I connect the hair to the head. I'll go ahead and upload the file anyway though